# Problem sorting matrix/array: indexing and value errors

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm writing a program in C which:

1. Takes in `int k` (positive integer)
2. Let user input a k*k matrix `a[k][k]`
3. Prompt user for further action
4. Do the chosen function

In this case, I'm having problems only with my `sort()` function which is called when the user chooses `p`. It sorts the matrix in ascending order and saves it in the file `s.txt`.

What I'm trying here is:

1. Turn the matrix `x[k][k]` into an array `arr[k*k]`
2. Use ascending bubble sort on the array
3. Write it to `s.txt` as a 2D matrix.

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Declaring variables

static int k;
static int *ptr;

// Declaring functions

void sum(int x[k][k]);
void prime(int x[k][k]);
void sort(int x[k][k]);
void r(int x[k][k]);

bool isprime(int *x);
bool sorted(int x[]);

// The main function

int main()
{
    char c = ' ';
    printf("Enter a value for k: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    int a[k][k];
    int arr[k*k];
    int t = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            printf("i[%d][%d] : ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("What do you wanna do with that?\n[e|a|p|s|r]\n");
    scanf(" %c", &c);

    switch (c)
    {
        case 'e':
        // do nothing
            break;

        case 'a':
        // sum all
            printf("Doing 'a'...\n");
            sum(a);
            break;

        case 'p': 
        // sum primes
            printf("Doing 'p'...\n");
            prime(a);
            break;

        case 's': 
        // sort ascending and print
            printf("Doing 's'...\n");
            sort(a);
            break;

        case 'r':
        // read from file and multiply
            printf("Doing 'r'...\n");
            r(a);
            for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
                {
                    printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            break;

        default: 
            printf("You got defaulted! Did you do something wrong?\n");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Defining the functions

void sum(int x[k][k])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            sum += x[i][j];
        }
    }
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("a.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", sum);
    fclose(fp);
}

void prime(int x[k][k])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            if(isprime(&x[i][j]))
            {
                sum += x[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("p.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", sum);
    fclose(fp);
}

void sort(int x[k][k])
{
    int tmp;

    int arr[k*k];

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            printf("x[%d][%d] : %d\n", i, j, x[i][j]);
            arr[(i*k)+j] = x[i][j];
            printf("arr[%d][%d] : %d\n", i, j, arr[(i*k)+j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nStill debugging...\n\n");

    // sorting
    while(!sorted(arr))
    {
        for(int l = 0; l < k*k; l++)
        {
            if(arr[l] > arr[l+1])
            {
                printf("arr[%d] : %d\n", l, arr[l]);
                printf("arr[%d+1] : %d\n", l, arr[l+1]);
                tmp = arr[l+1];
                arr[l+1] = arr[l];
                arr[l] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("s.txt", "w");

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "%d\t", arr[i]);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

void r(int x[k][k])
{
    int mul;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("r.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &mul);
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            x[i][j] = x[i][j] * mul;
        }
    }
}

bool isprime(int *x)
{
    if(*x == 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i = 2; i < *x; i++)
    {
        if(!(*x%i))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

bool sorted(int x[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < k*k-1; i++)
    {
        if(x[i] > x[i+1])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Just the `sort()` function (being updated as I'm trying to solve this with SO):

```
void sort(int x[k][k])
{
    int tmp;

    int arr[k*k];

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            printf("x[%d][%d] : %d\n", i, j, x[i][j]);
            arr[(i*j)+j] = x[i][j];
            printf("arr[%d][%d] : %d\n", i, j, arr[(i*j)+j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nStill debugging...\n\n");

    // sorting
    while(!sorted(arr))
    {
        for(int m = 0; m < k*k - 1; m++)
        {
            if(arr[m] > arr[m+1])
            {
                printf("arr[%d] : %d\n", m, arr[m]);
                printf("arr[%d+1] : %d\n", m, arr[m+1]);
                tmp = arr[m+1];
                arr[m+1] = arr[m];
                arr[m] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("s.txt", "w");

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "%d\t", arr[i]);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

I've added some `printf` lines for debugging. When I run the code with the following inputs:

```
Enter a value for k: 3
i[0][0] : 9
i[0][1] : 8
i[0][2] : 7
i[1][0] : 6
i[1][1] : 5
i[1][2] : 4
i[2][0] : 3
i[2][1] : 2
i[2][2] : 1
What do you wanna do with that?
[e|a|p|s|r]
s
```

I got this file:

```
$ cat s.txt 
1   1   1   
2   2   2   
3   3   3
```

... and here is my debugging output:

```
Doing 's'...
x[0][0] : 9
arr[0][0] : 9
x[0][1] : 8
arr[0][1] : 8
x[0][2] : 7
arr[0][2] : 7
x[1][0] : 6
arr[1][0] : 6
x[1][1] : 5
arr[1][1] : 5
x[1][2] : 4
arr[1][2] : 4
x[2][0] : 3
arr[2][0] : 3
x[2][1] : 2
arr[2][1] : 2
x[2][2] : 1
arr[2][2] : 1

Still debugging...

arr[0] : 9
arr[0+1] : 8
arr[1] : 9
arr[1+1] : 7
arr[2] : 9
arr[2+1] : 6
arr[3] : 9
arr[3+1] : 5
arr[4] : 9
arr[4+1] : 4
arr[5] : 9
arr[5+1] : 3
arr[6] : 9
arr[6+1] : 2
arr[7] : 9
arr[7+1] : 1
arr[0] : 8
arr[0+1] : 7
arr[1] : 8
arr[1+1] : 6
arr[2] : 8
arr[2+1] : 5
arr[3] : 8
arr[3+1] : 4
arr[4] : 8
arr[4+1] : 3
arr[5] : 8
arr[5+1] : 2
arr[6] : 8
arr[6+1] : 1
arr[0] : 7
arr[0+1] : 6
arr[1] : 7
arr[1+1] : 5
arr[2] : 7
arr[2+1] : 4
arr[3] : 7
arr[3+1] : 3
arr[4] : 7
arr[4+1] : 2
arr[5] : 7
arr[5+1] : 1
arr[0] : 6
arr[0+1] : 5
arr[1] : 6
arr[1+1] : 4
arr[2] : 6
arr[2+1] : 3
arr[3] : 6
arr[3+1] : 2
arr[4] : 6
arr[4+1] : 1
arr[0] : 5
arr[0+1] : 4
arr[1] : 5
arr[1+1] : 3
arr[2] : 5
arr[2+1] : 2
arr[3] : 5
arr[3+1] : 1
arr[0] : 4
arr[0+1] : 3
arr[1] : 4
arr[1+1] : 2
arr[2] : 4
arr[2+1] : 1
arr[0] : 3
arr[0+1] : 2
arr[1] : 3
arr[1+1] : 1
arr[0] : 2
arr[0+1] : 1
```

I'm kinda confused as to why it's giving me `0`s, `1`s and `2`s

Comment: `arr[(i*j)+j] = x[i][j];` should be `arr[(i*k)+j] = x[i][j];`  (note where `k` is)

Comment: Thank you. I've edited and updated the problem.

Comment: When `l = k*k-1` what is `tmp = arr[l+1]` (is `arr` still in bounds?) Also using lower case `'l'` as a variable is just asking for problems. It looks almost exactly like a `1` :)` Any reason you want to write your own sort instead of using `qsort`? It's orders of magnitude more efficient, and much more well tested that rolling your own.

Comment: This is supposed to be for practice so there are some restrictions. Writing my own bubble sort also lets me practice.

Comment: I forgot I had the ```+ 1```... still not quite done yet though but slowly getting there~

Comment: It is good practice, but my point being you can replace your sort with a simple `compare` function and `qsort` (I also have it outputting the sorted array). [qsort 2d as 1d snippet](https://paste.opensuse.org/15144437) You may want to try replacing your sort with that for testing purposes. You can remove the print loop when you are satisfied it is doing what you want (I do like `'m'` much better)

Comment: OK I've solved it. I also had a problem where I wrote ```arr[(i*j)+j]``` instead of  ```arr[(i*k)+j]``` where I print to file.

Comment: Good for you. I had a bubble sort to post, but if you have yours going, well done.